# read the specific records in file using c

Tags: c, file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct cust
{
   char accno[20],name[30],addr1[60],addr2[60],city[20],acctype[2],phno[20];
   int accbal;
};
void calcTime()  //function to show the current date and time
{
  time_t ts;
  ts=time(NULL);
  printf(ctime(&ts));
}
int main()
{
  char buf[100],a='y',b='y',c='y';
  int amount,total,j,i=0,k=0,l=0;
  struct cust c;
  FILE *p;
  p=fopen("data.DAT","a");
  do
   {
    printf("enter the account number\n");
    scanf("%s", c.accno);
    printf("enter the name and city of customer\n");
    scanf("%s %s",c.name,c.city);
    printf("enter the addr1 and addr2 of the customer\n");
    scanf("%s %s",c.addr1,c.addr2);
    printf("enter the phone no of customer\n");
    scanf("%s",&c.phno);
    printf("enter the account bal of customer\n");
    scanf("%d", &c.accbal);
    printf("enter the account type(s/c)=\n");
    scanf("%s",c.acctype);
      if(strcmp(c.acctype,"s")==0)
        {
          printf("saving account type\n");
        }
      else
         {
           if(strcmp(c.acctype,"c")==0)
            {
              printf("current account type\n");
             }
           else
             {
              printf("enter the currect account type\n");
              scanf("%s,c.acctype");
             }
         }
fseek(p,sizeof(c),SEEK_END);   // set curser point at the end
fwrite(&c,sizeof(c),1,p); //write the details  in file
printf("do you want to type another customer detail(y/n)?=\n");
scanf(" %c",&a);
if(a=='n') 
{
  i=1;
}
}while(!i);
do
{
  printf("enter the account number\n");
  scanf("%s",buf);      //getting the value in buffer
  fseek(p,sizeof(c),SEEK_SET);//set the cursor point at the beginning of file
  while(fread(&c,sizeof(c),1,p))       //read the file
  if(strcmp(buf,c.accno)==0)      //comparing the account number
  {
  do
  {
 printf("enter the choice\n");
 printf("1.view the detail\n");
 printf("2.Deposit the account\n");
 printf("3.view balance amount\n");
 printf("4.amount withdrawl\n");
 scanf("%d",&j);
 switch(j)
 {
  case 1:
    printf("your acc details are follows\n");
    printf("name of the customer=%s\n",c.name);
    printf("city of the customer=%s\n",c.city);
    printf("address1 of customer=%s\n",c.addr1);
    printf("address2 of customer=%s\n",c.addr2);
    printf("balance amount=%d\n",c.accbal);
    printf("phone number of customer=%s\n",&c.phno);
    printf("type of account=%s\n",c.acctype);
    break;
  case 2:
    printf("enter the amount to be deposited=\n");
    scanf("%d",&amount);
    total=c.accbal+amount;
    printf("total value is=%d\n",total);
    c.accbal=total;
    break;
  case 3:
    printf("your balance amount is=%d\n",c.accbal);
    break;
  case 4:
    printf("enter the amount to withdraw=\n");
    scanf("%d",&amount);
    if(amount>c.accbal)
     {
       printf("insufficient balance\n");
     }
    else
     {
       total=c.accbal-amount;
       printf("collect the cash amount\n");
       printf("balance amount=%d\n",total);
       c.accbal=total;
     }
    break;
 default :
    printf("enter the correct choice");
    scanf("%d",j);
    break;
 }
printf("do you want to continue (y/n)=\n");
scanf(" %c",&b);
if(b=='n')
 {
  k=1;
 }while(!k);
 }
printf("Do you need to access another record(y/n)=\n");
scanf(" %c",&c);
if(c=='n')
{ 
l=1;
}while(!l);
}
printf("thanks for using the service\n");
calcTime();
fclose(p);
getchar();
return(0);
}
```

1. I wrote the detail of two records in the file  but  while reading the file i got  the 2nd record only.
   first record is not shown. what is the error in the codings?
2. please some one tell what is the error.

Comment: `scanf("%s,c.acctype");` --> `scanf("%s", c.acctype);`, `printf("phone number of customer=%s\n",&c.phno);` --> `printf("phone number of customer=%s\n", c.phno);`, `fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c",&b);` --> `scanf(" %c",&b);`, `scanf("%d",j);` --> `scanf("%d", &j);`

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to use `goto`, like multi-level `break`s or error-handling. Your code shouldn't use goto.

Comment: Thanks a lot goto is the main problem in my program... now i got the output..

Comment: You should have presented the corrections as an answer, not by modifying the question and thus making it meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems in your code -

```
printf("phone number of customer=%s\n",&c.phno);
                                       ^remove this 
scanf("%s,c.acctype");` should be -`scanf("%s",c.acctype);

scanf("%s",&c.phno);
           ^ you don't need this
```

And you should stop using this -

```
fflush(stdin);
```

It has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. but when i remove fflush  i cannot get the input y/n correctly??

Comment: @SathyaSri  I would say leave a space before `%c` in `scanf` . Like this -`scanf(" %c",&a)` . So you wont need `fflush` .

Comment: @SathyaSri  Reading file problem persists now or not ?

Comment: still there is  problem sir. i changed the mode in to w+ .now it reads first record only

Comment: @SathyaSri If you take `w+` then as you run program again previous records will be discarded .No need to change mode .